# NodeJS process disconnects on SSH session logout

Tags: node.js, unix, ssh, nohup, forever

I am doing SSH on the server, which is Ubuntu 14.04 server. I tried various things to keep the Node server running. But as soon as I type exit and disconnect the server from my Ubuntu Desktop the Node server is also disconnected. 
Though it is running on the server. When I SSH into the server I can access it.

I have tried these :

```
nohup node server.js & 

nohup node server.js > /dev/null 2> error.log < /dev/null &

sudo nohup supervisor server.js &

forever start server.js
```

Also I tried using tmux and screen. Its the same problem with all of these. As soon as I disconnect the SSH the node server is not available. But when I just login to the server, it is available again.

What am I missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [http://askubuntu.com/questions/349262/run-a-nohup-command-over-ssh-then-disconnect](http://askubuntu.com/questions/349262/run-a-nohup-command-over-ssh-then-disconnect)

Answer (score 0):

> Though it is running on the server

seems to contradict

> As soon I disconnect the ssh, it terminates

Are you doing anything special with your ssh session? ( like forwarding server port to a client ) How do you check if server is running?

Possible reasons:

1) You test using server's localhost when on server and server IP from client: check you are binding your server to "0.0.0.0" address and not 127.0.0.1

2) You have some kind of port forwarding and connect to server vi client localhost:forvarded_port -> ssh -> server localhost:remote forward side port. - Checj you are listening on 0.0.0.0, that server IP is not blocked by firewall and try to access it via direct ip/port

Comment: What I mean by though it is running on the server is, when I ssh into the server, even if I do not start the node server it is running. I can start accessing my application. When I disconnect SSH I can no more access the application. Server is in LAN. This server has a static IP. Tried accessing via both the LAN and static IP's. But it does not work.

Comment: what do you mean by "accessing"? Browsing to a url with chrome? Telnetting to a port? Something else?

Comment: Yes browsing to the url with chrome.